# Electron in Magnetic Field can lead to non-Hermitian Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

Consider a charged quantum particle in a magnetic field. The Hamiltonian can be written using minimal coupling:
$$
H = \frac{1}{2m} \left( \mathbf{p} - \frac{e}{c} \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) \right)^2
$$

where $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})$ is the vector potential.

If one expands this, one gets:
$$
H = \frac{1}{2m} \left\{ \mathbf{p}^2 + \left(\frac{e}{c}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\right)^2 - \frac{2 e}{c} \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) ~\mathbf{p} - \frac{e}{c} \underbrace{\left[ \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) \right]}_{\textrm{commutator}}  \right\}
$$

Now, the commutator becomes
$$[\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})] = (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}))~~ [\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{x}] = -i (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}))$$
which is imaginary and independent of momentum.

Now, this term drops out when one is in the Coulomb gauge. But if one picks a different gauge, say $\mathbf{A} = ( xy, 0, 0)$ for a gradient magnetic field, **doesn't such a term make the Hamiltonian non-Hermitian?** Which would in turn lead to complex energy eigenvalues?

Or, else, do we have to insist on using the Coulomb gauge for non-relativistic problems?

Comment: I have encountered this situation once before whilst studying the quantum Hall effect, check out these lecture notes http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1998 Chapter 2 and especially  page 35.

Answer (score 4):

Since the Hamiltonian $2mH$ is self-adjoint$^1$ (the square of a Hermitian operator is again Hermitian), there is formally no problem. If one of the terms
$$- \frac{e}{c} \left[ \mathbf{p}, \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) \right]$$

in the Hamiltonian $2mH$ is non-Hermitian, there must be other non-Hermitian terms that cancel any non-Hermitian effect in the full Hamiltonian $2mH$. In this case the culprit is

$$ - \frac{2 e}{c} \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) ~\mathbf{p}, $$

which is non-Hermitian as well.

--

$^1$ Here we ignore potential problems related to [domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators) of [unbounded operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), i.e. we do not properly distinguish between [symmetric](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Symmetric_operator), Hermitian, and [self-adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator) operators.